# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key errors shown on google play console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

When I get upload .aap file on google play consol. google play show an error messege like this:

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: 6B:9B:F0:4F:5C:98:26:BB:90:40:11:60:18:AA:A9:6A:DF:E3:4B:FF
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: A1:DA:6E:12:E3:04:85:77:CB:FD:7C:7B:53:A9:F3:E5:E9:71:21:E8

I create the app using android studio

Comment: i think you are trying to upload it to the wrong project, make sure you are uploading the correct project, because the key bundle you are trying to upload doesn't match. Check and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message indicates that the keystore you used to sign the app bundle is a different one from the first version you uploaded.

The app bundle you upload to Play Console always needs to be signed with the same key (called the "upload key"). So find the keystore you used to sign the first version of your app you uploaded to Play Console and use that keystore to sign your app bundle.